# why take screen shot from framebuffer is very slow on android?

Tags: android, screenshot, framebuffer, frame-rate

Taking screenshot from framebuffer with /dev/graphics/fb0 is very slow(200~300ms).
How can i make it faster?

byte[] request = formAdbRequest("framebuffer:");

Answer (score 3):

> byte[] request = formAdbRequest("framebuffer:");

You are not strictly "taking screenshot from framebuffer with /dev/graphics/fb0" if that is the code that you are using.

Instead, you are running code on the development machine that sends a message over the USB connection that is picked up by a daemon process on the Android device that takes a screenshot and sends it back down the USB connection to the development machine.

> is very slow(200~300ms). How can i make it faster?

Generally speaking, you can't, without modifying aspects of the Android OS, or rolling your own screenshot logic on a rooted device.